# emberjs ArrayController doesn't work in template

Tags: ember.js

I am trying out ember.js and I am struggling with rendering an array of items to the template:

**index.html**

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{App.test}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#each App.eventsController}}
        <p>{{title}}</p>
    {{/each}}
  </script>

  <!-- le javascript -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.0.0.beta.6.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-1.0.pre.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
var App = Em.Application.create({
    test : 'does it work?...'
});

App.Event = Ember.Object.extend({
    title: '',
    body: ''
});

App.eventsController = Ember.ArrayController.create({

    events: [],

    init: function() {

        self = this;
        self.pushObject(App.Event.create({
            title: "Event 1",
            body: "Content"
        }));
    }
});
```

The first binding (`App.test`) does work fine. Only my second call does nothing but putting an empty handlebar-script-tag into my DOM.

So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

If you override `init` you need to make sure to call `this._super` so the controller can finish its setup process. Once you do this your code should be working as expected.

```
init: function() {
    this._super();
    this.get('content').pushObject(App.Event.create({
        title: "Event 1",
        body: "Content"
    }));
}
```

I've created a jsfiddle for you so you can see it working: http://jsfiddle.net/qKXJt/188/

Comment: Your code also works without that super call... I will try that in my environment later. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to put your eventsController's data inside the 'content' property:

```
App.eventsController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],

    init: function() {
        this.get('content').pushObject(App.Event.create({
            title: "Event 1",
            body: "Content"
        }));
    }
});
```

Your template {{#each App.eventsController}} should automatically pick up the changes and display your title.

Comment: My chrome console says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'oushObject' of null". I feel like I am doing something very basic wrong... :-/

Comment: Might be a silly question, but do you have a statement at the top of app.'s with var App = Ember.Application.create({}); and an App.initialize(); at the end of app.js ?

Comment: I do create the app. I don't initialize it! I tried it and it made no difference. But as far as I know I don't have to initialize it?!

Comment: I think in 1.0pre you have to explicitly call `App.initialize()`. I am using ember-latest and they have just changed this behaviour again by setting `autoinit: true`. So in ember-latest right now you no longer need to call initialize()